# handle server shutdown while serving http request

Tags: http, error-handling

Scenario : The server is in middle of processing a http request and the server shuts down. There are multiple points till where the code has executed. How are such cases typically handled ?. A typical example could be that some downstream http calls had to be made as a part of the incoming http request. How to find whether such calls were made or not made when the shutdown occurred. I assume that its not possible to persist every action in the code flow. Suggestions and views are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of shutdowns to consider here.

There are **graceful** shutdowns: when the execution environment politely asks your process to stop (e.g. [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) sends a [SIGTERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html)) and expects it to exit on its own. If your process doesn’t exit within a few seconds, the environment proceeds to kill the process in a more forceful way.

A typical way to handle a graceful shutdown is:

1. listen for the signal from the environment
2. when you receive the signal, stop accepting **new** requests...
3. ...and then wait for all **current** requests to finish

Exactly how you do this depends on your platform/framework. For instance, Go’s standard [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) library provides a [`Server.Shutdown`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown) method.

In a typical system, most shutdowns will be graceful. For example, when you need to restart your process to deploy a new version of code, you do a graceful shutdown.

There can also be **unexpected** shutdowns: e.g. when you suddenly lose power or network connectivity (a disconnected server is usually as good as a dead one). Such faults are harder to deal with. There’s an entire body of research dedicated to making distributed systems robust to arbitrary faults. In the simple case, when your server only writes to a single database, you can open a  [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/tutorial-transactions.html) at the beginning of a request and commit it before returning the response. This will guarantee that either all the changes are saved to the database or none of them are. But if you call multiple downstream services as part of one upstream HTTP request, you need to coordinate them, for example, with a [saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

For some applications, it may be OK to ignore unexpected shutdowns and simply deal with any inconsistencies manually if/when they arise. This depends on your application.